# How to Cutomize new Date() to only show required fileds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm am trying to set my `this.state.date` to something like DD/MM/YYYY. in order to obtain the date, I used a library https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

I am currently able to pick my desired date and. However, when I set the state of date to it, I get something like this `Sun Jul 18 2020 18:21:15 GMT+:4:00...`

How can I customize this? Here is my code snippet where I set the state of date to the selected date:

```
handleConfirmDate(date){
        this.setState({
            date: new Date(date).toString(),
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can to this this way

```js
var newDate = new Date(),
    datestring = '';

datestring = newDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (newDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' + newDate.getDate()

console.log(datestring);
```